# Why expl3 conflicts with "gather" environment?

Tags: l3regex, gather

This code works just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{}
  {\filecontentsdefmacro\l__foo_tmp_tl}
  {\endfilecontentsdefmacro%
  \str_set:NV \l__foo_tmp_tl \l__foo_tmp_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{X} \l__foo_tmp_tl
  \l__foo_tmp_tl}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{foo}
test me please
\end{foo}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It renders `tX stmX plX asX fl` (each letter `e` replaced with `X`). However, if I change `equation` to `gather` from `amsmath`, the regex replacement is not happening. What's so special about `gather` and how to fix this?

Comment: The `amsmath` environments usually try to grab their contents which will tokenize their input. I'd guess that `filecontentsdef` doesn't like that fact...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what filecontentsdef is doing, but you could use the LaTeX +b argument type instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx} 
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{+b} 
  {\tl_set:Nn\l__foo_tmp_tl{#1}}
  {\str_set:NV \l__foo_tmp_tl \l__foo_tmp_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{X} \l__foo_tmp_tl
  \l__foo_tmp_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{foo}
test me please
\end{foo}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now, `#1` doesn't contain `^^M` for ends-of-line :(

Comment: @yegor256 And what would be the problem? Lines in gather should be separated by ``\\``

Comment: I'm trying to make this `foo` environment work inside or outside of `gather`. I need it to capture the input "as it is" letting me do the pre-processing and interpreting `^^M` symbols. WDYT, is it possible?

Comment: Gather (like all the other amsmath environments) collects its body too, and that means that catcode tricks inside are not possible.